# SSRS layout and column visibility

Tags: layout, reporting-services, visibility

I have about 40 columns that I need to hide/display based on certain conditions. At any given time there would not be more than 10 columns( do not know which ones) that could get displayed. I need to make sure that the report is rendered in letter paper size, though in landscape orientation. I have added all the columns to the table and have set the can grow to True. Despite it when I run the report I get the data that I want a about 2 extra blank pages. Any suggestions why those are displayed and also if there is a way to control this? The report runs off of a stored procedure.

Comment: You probably have all 40 columns showing on your report design... and then hiding what you don't want to show. This leaves a lot of blank space on the report.. which turns into blank pages. Why not get the SP to return just the columns you want and then display just those?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Harry. Originally that is what I was hoping to do. But I can never be sure of which columns shall be returned in the SP and so I would never know which columns to add on the report. I wish there was a way that when the Cangrow property is set to true the growth happens horizontally instead of vertically. That way I can set the size of the table to the size I need and the columns that are being displayed will do so with the correct width.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to set all columns at 1mm width with CanGrow=True?

Comment: As I mentioned above CanGrow = True will only increase the height of the column, not horizontally.

Comment: Sorry I misread the answer. Did you take a look at [THIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/949ce45d-0f55-4119-bfe1-8f8b1fb8804e/auto-grow-textbox-width-?forum=sqlreportingservices)? It's a workround to grow horizontally, it may worth a try.
That said, I really suggest you to do the hard work with a stored procedure. It cleaner and surely you can find a way to get only non-empty columns